# NDK NativeActivity on top of JavaApplication with WebView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ndk, native-activity

I am looking for a way to have part of my OpenGL [`NativeActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html) transparent on top of a Java application with a web view so I can have a browser in my application. Porting the WebKit is problematic and taking more time than I have. Does any one know how to render my OpenGL like an overlay on top of another applications ?